# Inserting a div after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to 'move' a `div` from one location to another. I'm using `.after`, but it doesn't call the method? What am I doing wrong?

```js
var row = $('<div class="row">Another row inserted</div>');
$('.container').append(row);

$('.button').click(function() {
 $('.row').addClass('row-changed');
 $('.container:eq(2)').after(row);
});
```

```css
.row {
  color: blue;
}
.row-changed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <button class='button'>Move</button>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.container:eq(2)` ? there is only one `.container` in your document. Also, please add your code within your question.

Comment: `$('.row:eq(2)').after(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to select the nth child of the `.container`, `.container:eq(2)` will not work since it is trying to select the second `.container`, not the second child of the `.container`. You can use the `:nth-child()` selector instead.

**jQuery**

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.row').addClass('row-changed');
    $('.container > div:nth-child(2)').after(row);
});
```

```js
var row = $('<div class="row">Another row inserted</div>');
$('.container').append(row);

$('.button').click(function() {
 $('.row').addClass('row-changed');
 $('.container > div:nth-child(2)').after(row);
});
```

```css
.row {
  color: blue;
}
.row-changed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <button class='button'>Move</button>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
  <div class='row'>Row here</div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkfb4pdu/1/)**

Comment: Is there a way to move with it an animation? Like have it slide up into place, instead of just popping in there?

Comment: Since you're using `.after` it's directly inserting the content, so you'll need to use another method if you want it to animate.